# Estimating lithium-ion battery run time at different voltages

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, load, discharge, charge

A polymer lithium battery in a powerbank (marketed as 30,000 mAh / 3.8 V, 114 Wh), has an actual electric capacity of 19,944 mAh, and an energy capacity of 104 Wh as measured with a constant load connected non-stop to the powerbank's USB-A output that was drawing 5.21 V  / 1.50 A for 13:18 hh:mm (until the powerbank "died", the voltage remained constant to the end).

For how many hours can this powerbank power a device that draws 9.2 V / 0.5 A from the powerbank's USB-C port? How does draining at different voltages alter the equation of battery run time? (USB-A and -C outputs are rated from 5 V / 2 A to 20 V / 3.25 A.)

Is 104 Wh / 4.6 W = 22.6 h the best estimation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 5V out of 3.8V battery requires an use of step-up switching converter. To get 9V, similar (or the same converter) will be required. Your measurements in 5-V mode indicate that the built-in converter has efficiency of about 87%, (which is pretty good), so the efficiency of the device with variable Li-Ion (internal) voltage is already factored in the 104Wh number. So your estimation looks correct, maybe should be a little lower since efficiency of switchers decreases with more difference between Vin and Vout.

Comment: For example, 20V / 0.23A or 9.2V / 0.5A or 5V/ 0.92A are all 4.6W. So the battery will run for 104Wh/4.6W = 22.6 h under any of these three voltage / amperage configs?

Comment: @user3026965, "22.6 h under any of these three voltage / amperage configs?" - not exactly, as I said, DC-DC conversion efficiency will be lower with higher output voltage. How lower - hard to tell, all depends on design quality.